# Firebase data loading strange behavior (too slow at times)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Earlier it was all working great, recently I updated my device to Nougat and experiencing certain issues.

- When the device is online, the data loads quickly.
- When offline, and the device goes online it takes almost **2 plus** minutes to load data (earlier this was not the case).

What might be the issue? Is it Firebase or Android nougat issue?

My guess is firebase is taking too much time to connect to the server when the device goes online.

Comment: are you checking firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnSuccessListener() .... everytime before making a request to firebase for data ??

Comment: @Rahul No. do I have to?

Comment: no u need not, can you share your code ?

Comment: Turn on debug logging.  Does it suggest anything about how it performs retries when the network isn't available?  `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.DEBUG);`

Comment: @Rahul Sure....

Comment: @DougStevenson Where should I set it? In the activity or Application?